# Strange icon behavior with sponsored tags in revision view

Tags: bug, status-completed, sponsored-tags

When I view a question's edit in the revision view, any edits to sponsored tags cause that tag's icon to be displayed offset a few pixels from where I'd expect it to show.

[image]

I've reproduced this in Chrome 13 and IE 9 on Windows, and Safari on iOS. I saw this with the Facebook tags, [as shown above](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7381846/revisions), and found it also on [google-chrome questions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/308125/revisions). The tags display properly in the standard views (obviously, I guess).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed in the next build.

The recent improvements to the diff engine finally handle images (added images get a green border etc.) – and for the diff engine, those sponsor images are just images that were added. However this case wasn't handled quite correctly, and of course this isn't very helpful anyway (besides being ugly), so after the build the sponsor images won't have a special styling even in the diff case.

I hadn't noticed this because on my development machine, I didn't have any sponsored tags.

I do now.

[image]